# Jquery - changing server IP Address and getting no result back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a simple php page which contains a form for the user to enter IP Address, Subnet Mask, Gateway, DNS etc.

When they submit this I'm using JQuery & AJAX to pass those values back to a php page on the server. That page calls a local daemon which then changes the network configuration of the server the page is running from.

Normally I access this page via 127.0.0.1, I submit the change, the servers IP address updates and I get a response on screen advising the LAN IP Settings have been updated.  This all works FINE.

Now I'm trying to use the same page via the server LAN IP Address. When I submit the new details the server updates correctly in the background but I get nothing back. So I've no idea if it worked or not.

The ajax I'm using is :

```
$.ajax({ url: link,
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log (data)
        },

        error: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log (data)
        }
});
```

So nothing fancy. I assume the issue is either do to the server network card being restarted or simply because the IP Address has changed.

Is there any way to get a response back to advise if this has been changed or not ?

Comment: You need to share your PHP code. This isn't a problem with jQuery.

Comment: The php code just creates some text files and passes values to a bash script (daemon) which has permissions to make the network changes. When the php code finishes it var_dumps the results from the exec command and it's that which is read via the ajax return.. but nothing is shown. This works fine on localhost, but not the LAN IP Address

Comment: if you change the IP address of the server, the first connection is not available anynnore and this returns nothing. Instead of using Ajax you could post the data and reload the page with the new address

Comment: check your browser's developer tools, in the Console and Network areas, and look for console errors, and at the ajax request (in the network tab) to see what response you're getting, if any, and what it looks like. Maybe there's some sort of HTTP error.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The console shows nothing.  I'm looking at adding a pause to allow the process to complete, then checking if the page is accessible on the new IP Address, if it is redirect, if not check the old address and failing that show an error !

Comment: Try showing a print-screen with the headers of the url request made through ajax as it appears in DevTools->Network. I may be wrong but to me execution flow should be: page has an IP, ajax fires request to same IP; IP changes on server -> ajax should query new IP to confirm change performed with success. Now CORS should not allow ajax to run ... nightmare. I would rather check at the new IP for something like an existing page on server with $.ajax({url:'xxx.dat',type:'HEAD',error:console.log("alert")}); maybe in a loop, then redirect browser to server's new IP.

Comment: I am hitting CORS when I try to see if URL exists. is there anyway to check URL or file exists with out upsetting CORS ?

Comment: I seem to have got around the CORS using an AJAX request with a datatype of `jsonp`